# uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then not running on Android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I've integrated angular-google-maps into my Ionic project - in index.html I have:

```
<script src="lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
```

In my view HTML I have:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content controller="WeatherController">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In app.js I have:

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'mygmapskey',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
});
```

Inside style.css I have:

```
.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }
```

And, finally, inside my WeatherController I have:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
```

...

```
.controller("WeatherController", function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    console.log('WeatherController');
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        console.log('maps API loaded; creating map');
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
    });
});
```

When I run ionic serve, I get a nice map in the browser which works fine. When I run it on Android (either the emulator or my physical device) the WeatherController is instantiated but uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then never fires. Is this not intended to run on devices? I couldn't see much mention of it on the site.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be due to the minification. When minifying, you have to use array injection syntax:

```
.controller("WeatherController", [
  '$scope',
  'uiGmapGoogleMapApi',
  function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
      console.log('WeatherController');
      uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
          console.log('maps API loaded; creating map');
          $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
      });
  }
]);
```

You are already using this syntax when declaring your main module starter.

Comment: This is most interesting, I did wonder what the difference between those syntaxes were. However, it doesn't make it run on Android. :)